# Firebase user roles

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

I am trying to create an application with React and Firebase. I am new in Firebase and I have a problem with User Roles. How we can define user roles of system_users, how do I know if user is admin or just a client. Based on that I need to show different part of pages in the web. How can I save different roles for users ? Attached you can find the system_users part in Firebase, how to differentiate these users as admin or client.[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? What defines user roles? Can you share your Firebase structure for your users (as text please, no images)? How are you defining admin or clients?

Comment: @Jay I have added the image. I just want to add  user roles also, is it admin user or client user. I am using createUserWithEmailAndPassword function to create users in Firebase.

Comment: ugh. Please READ. *as text please, no images* 'We' don't like retyping structures as it takes a lot of time when it could be copied and pasted as text.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866220/how-to-read-write-from-one-ios-app-set-up-with-firebase-to-another-firebase-dat?noredirect=1#comment76723140_44866220) and the answer I just wrote. There's some swift code and the actual questions are different but the concepts in the answer matches what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks @Jay it was very helpful :)